# Check for existence of Python dev files from bash script

Tags: python, bash

I am creating a simple bash script to download and install a python Nagios plugin. On some older servers the script may need to install the subprocess module and as a result I need to make sure the correct python-devel files are installed.

What is an appropriate and cross platform method of checking for these files. Would like to stay away from rpm or apt.

If you can tell me how to do the check from within python that would work. Thanks!

Update:

This is the best I have come up with. Anyone know a better or more conclusive method?

```
if [ ! -e $(python -c 'from distutils.sysconfig import get_makefile_filename as m; print m()') ]; then echo "Sorry"; fi
```

Comment: any reason RPM is not your favorite?

Comment: I would need to determine distro and run rpm and the dpkg (apt) equivalent. So if at all possible I'd rather not have all that code. If I can just do some sort of "python -c import development-stuff" within the bash script and check exit status that would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be pretty much how I would go about doing it. Seems reasonable simple.

However, if I need to be really sure that `python-devel` files are installed for the current version of Python, I would look for the relevant `Python.h` file. Something along the lines of:

```
# first, makes sure distutils.sysconfig usable
if ! $(python -c "import distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars" &> /dev/null); then
    echo "ERROR: distutils.sysconfig not usable" >&2
    exit 2
fi

# get include path for this python version
INCLUDE_PY=$(python -c "from distutils import sysconfig as s; print s.get_config_vars()['INCLUDEPY']")
if [ ! -f "${INCLUDE_PY}/Python.h" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: python-devel not installed" >&2
    exit 3
fi
```

**Note**: `distutils.sysconfig` may not be supported on all platforms so not the most portable solution, but still better than trying to cater for variations in `apt`, `rpm` and the likes.

If you really need to support *all* platforms, it might be worth exploring what is done in the [AX_PYTHON_DEVEL](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=blob_plain;f=m4/ax_python_devel.m4) m4 module. This module can be used in a `configure.ac` script to incorporate checks for `python-devel` during the `./configure` stage of an [autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system)-based build.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the script to include the Python.h portion!

Answer (score 2):

Imho your solutions works well.

Otherwise, a more "elegant" solution would be to use a tiny script like:

testimport.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys

try:
  __import__(sys.argv[1])
  print "Sucessfully import", sys.argv[1]
except:
  print "Error!"
  sys.exit(4)

sys.exit(0)
```

And call it with testimport.sh distutils.sysconfig

You can adapt it to check for internal function if needed...

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a pure python solution that also works for python3:

```
python3 -c 'from distutils.sysconfig import get_makefile_filename as m; from os.path import isfile; import sys ; sys.exit(not isfile(m()))')
```

Or as a file script `check-py-dev.py`:

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_makefile_filename as m
from os.path import isfile 
import sys 
sys.exit(not isfile(m()))
```

To get a string in bash, just use the exit output:

```
python3 check-py-dev.py && echo "Ok" || echo "Error: Python header files NOT found"
```

Comment: I think your first code block has a trailing `)`