# Installing scipy on cygwin/win11

Tags: python-3.x, installation, scipy, cygwin

My python version is 3.9.10

I am currently trying to install python in cygwin via

```
python3 -m pip install scipy
```

I have so far installed, via the Cygwin installer:

- gcc-core
- gcc-g++
- libopenblas
- liblapack
- liblapack-devel
- gcc-fortran
- python39-devel
- python39-wheel

I have also used the solution from this thread to check whether the python-devel installation was successful: [Check for existence of Python dev files from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848566/check-for-existence-of-python-dev-files-from-bash-script)

Any suggestion would be appreciated,

Cheers.

Here is the last 100 lines of the lengthy error report:

```
      /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: error: static assertion failed: Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: note: ‘(0 == ((int)boost::integral_constant<bool, true>::value))’ evaluates to false
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::math::tools::promote_args<long double, float, float, float, float, float>’:
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/expm1.hpp:271:46:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, class Policy> typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<T>::type boost::math::expm1(T, const Policy&) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/ibeta_inverse.hpp:541:36:   required from ‘T boost::math::detail::ibeta_inv_imp(T, T, T, T, const Policy&, T*) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/ibeta_inverse.hpp:979:30:   required from ‘typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<T1, T2, T3, T4>::type boost::math::ibetac_inv(T1, T2, T3, T4*, const Policy&) [with T1 = long double; T2 = long double; T3 = long double; T4 = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::discrete_quantile<boost::math::policies::integer_round_up> >; typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<T1, T2, T3, T4>::type = long double]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/distributions/beta.hpp:524:24:   required from ‘RealType boost::math::quantile(const boost::math::complemented2_type<boost::math::beta_distribution<RealType, Policy>, RealType>&) [with RealType = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::discrete_quantile<boost::math::policies::integer_round_up> >]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/stats/_boost/include/func_defs.hpp:110:33:   required from ‘RealType boost_isf(RealType, const Args ...) [with Dst = boost::math::beta_distribution; RealType = long double; Args = {long double, long double}]’
  scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.cxx:3774:46:   required from here
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: error: static assertion failed: Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: note: ‘(0 == ((int)boost::integral_constant<bool, true>::value))’ evaluates to false
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::math::tools::promote_args<long double, long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>, float, float, float>’:
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/beta.hpp:1467:4:   required by substitution of ‘template<class RT1, class RT2, class A> typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<RT1, RT2, A>::type boost::math::beta(RT1, RT2, A) [with RT1 = long double; RT2 = long double; A = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/ibeta_inverse.hpp:607:51:   required from ‘T boost::math::detail::ibeta_inv_imp(T, T, T, T, const Policy&, T*) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/ibeta_inverse.hpp:979:30:   required from ‘typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<T1, T2, T3, T4>::type boost::math::ibetac_inv(T1, T2, T3, T4*, const Policy&) [with T1 = long double; T2 = long double; T3 = long double; T4 = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::discrete_quantile<boost::math::policies::integer_round_up> >; typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<T1, T2, T3, T4>::type = long double]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/distributions/beta.hpp:524:24:   required from ‘RealType boost::math::quantile(const boost::math::complemented2_type<boost::math::beta_distribution<RealType, Policy>, RealType>&) [with RealType = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::discrete_quantile<boost::math::policies::integer_round_up> >]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/stats/_boost/include/func_defs.hpp:110:33:   required from ‘RealType boost_isf(RealType, const Args ...) [with Dst = boost::math::beta_distribution; RealType = long double; Args = {long double, long double}]’
  scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.cxx:3774:46:   required from here
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: error: static assertion failed: Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: note: ‘(0 == ((int)boost::integral_constant<bool, true>::value))’ evaluates to false
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::math::tools::promote_args<long double, long double, float, float, float, float>’:
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/powm1.hpp:66:4:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T1, class T2, class Policy> typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<RT1, RT2>::type boost::math::powm1(T1, T2, const Policy&) [with T1 = long double; T2 = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/beta.hpp:1099:44:   required from ‘T boost::math::detail::ibeta_imp(T, T, T, const Policy&, bool, bool, T*) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/beta.hpp:1395:20:   required from ‘T boost::math::detail::ibeta_imp(T, T, T, const Policy&, bool, bool) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/beta.hpp:1534:93:   required from ‘typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<RT1, RT2, A>::type boost::math::ibeta(RT1, RT2, RT3, const Policy&) [with RT1 = long double; RT2 = long double; RT3 = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::discrete_quantile<boost::math::policies::integer_round_up> >; typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<RT1, RT2, A>::type = long double]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/distributions/beta.hpp:416:19:   required from ‘RealType boost::math::cdf(const boost::math::beta_distribution<RealType, Policy>&, const RealType&) [with RealType = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::discrete_quantile<boost::math::policies::integer_round_up> >]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/stats/_boost/include/func_defs.hpp:85:32:   required from ‘RealType boost_cdf(RealType, const Args ...) [with Dst = boost::math::beta_distribution; RealType = long double; Args = {long double, long double}]’
  scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.cxx:3252:46:   required from here
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: error: static assertion failed: Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: note: ‘(0 == ((int)boost::integral_constant<bool, true>::value))’ evaluates to false
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::math::tools::promote_args<long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>, float, float, float, float>’:
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:2002:4:   required by substitution of ‘template<class RT1, class RT2> typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<RT1, RT2>::type boost::math::tgamma(RT1, RT2) [with RT1 = long double; RT2 = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:1627:33:   required from ‘T boost::math::detail::tgamma_delta_ratio_imp(T, T, const Policy&) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:2126:106:   required from ‘typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<RT1, RT2>::type boost::math::tgamma_delta_ratio(T1, T2, const Policy&) [with T1 = long double; T2 = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>; typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<RT1, RT2>::type = long double]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/t_distribution_inv.hpp:136:41:   required from ‘T boost::math::detail::inverse_students_t_body_series(T, T, const Policy&) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/t_distribution_inv.hpp:390:73:   required from ‘T boost::math::detail::inverse_students_t(T, T, T, const Policy&, bool*) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/t_distribution_inv.hpp:424:49:   required from ‘T boost::math::detail::find_ibeta_inv_from_t_dist(T, T, T, T*, const Policy&) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/ibeta_inverse.hpp:532:37:   required from ‘T boost::math::detail::ibeta_inv_imp(T, T, T, T, const Policy&, T*) [with T = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/ibeta_inverse.hpp:979:30:   required from ‘typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<T1, T2, T3, T4>::type boost::math::ibetac_inv(T1, T2, T3, T4*, const Policy&) [with T1 = long double; T2 = long double; T3 = long double; T4 = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::discrete_quantile<boost::math::policies::integer_round_up> >; typename boost::math::tools::promote_args<T1, T2, T3, T4>::type = long double]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/distributions/beta.hpp:524:24:   required from ‘RealType boost::math::quantile(const boost::math::complemented2_type<boost::math::beta_distribution<RealType, Policy>, RealType>&) [with RealType = long double; Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::discrete_quantile<boost::math::policies::integer_round_up> >]’
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/stats/_boost/include/func_defs.hpp:110:33:   required from ‘RealType boost_isf(RealType, const Args ...) [with Dst = boost::math::beta_distribution; RealType = long double; Args = {long double, long double}]’
  scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.cxx:3774:46:   required from here
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: error: static assertion failed: Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:148:37: note: ‘(0 == ((int)boost::integral_constant<bool, true>::value))’ evaluates to false
    148 |          BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == ::boost::is_same<type, long double>::value), "Sorry, but this platform does not have sufficient long double support for the special functions to be reliably implemented.");
        |                                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost/boost/static_assert.hpp:31:59: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG’
     31 | #     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
        |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  error: Command "g++ -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DBOOST_MATH_DOMAIN_ERROR_POLICY=ignore_error -DBOOST_MATH_EVALUATION_ERROR_POLICY=user_error -DBOOST_MATH_OVERFLOW_ERROR_POLICY=user_error -DBOOST_MATH_PROMOTE_DOUBLE_POLICY=false -Iscipy/stats/_boost/include/ -Iscipy/stats/_boost/src/ -I/tmp/pip-build-env-ms79kstb/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-install-lggt3n7k/scipy_d9ae94430a22449eb2927159d9f7ad01/scipy/_lib/boost -I/tmp/pip-build-env-ms79kstb/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.cxx -o build/temp.cygwin-3.3.5-x86_64-3.9/scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.o -MMD -MF build/temp.cygwin-3.3.5-x86_64-3.9/scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.o.d -std=c++14" failed with exit status 1
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Probably relevant [Github Issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/15296)

Comment: I used the cygwin installer to get the `wheel` package to solve a similar problem. Check that you have the latest python 3.9 packages for `python39-pip`, `python39-setuptools`, `python39-wheel`, and any scipy dependencies that have cygwin packages. Use the cygwin package, even if it is not the latest, in preference to the PyPI package (i.e. the one pip will download). Unfortunately this is still a manual process for cygwin and some linux distros.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have currently pip 22.1.2 and setuptools 59.5.0 and wheel 0.37.1 installed. When I use the cygwin package manager it shows no python39-pip only (up to) 38. But looking at their website [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) tells me that I have the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with installing Scipy in Cygwin using pip3 install scipy.

However, I figure it out using my Windows' python. Originally, the Python version of Cygwin I am using is 3.9, which comes with problems of installation. I try to switch the Python to my Windows one, which is Python 3.11 and this one can import Scipy.

go to the root

```
cd ~ 
ls -a
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KisGW.png)

```
nano .bashrc

# add this command at the bottom of the file
export PATH= *Your_Windows'_Python_Address* :$PATH
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StDfZ.png)

Exit and save the change. Right now, you just switch Cygwin default python into your Windows python.

```
# Reload the file
source .bashrc


which python
python --version
```

I think you can import scipy right now.